# Self -Adjoint operator, Positive operator and invertibility

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Can you please help me with the following question which was asked in assignment of Functional Analysis?

Problem:  Let H be a complex Hilbert space and let $T\in L(H)$. (1)Show that if T is self -adjoint, then $T- \lambda I$ is invertible for for any complex number $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{R}$.

(2) Show that if T is positive, then $T+ aI$ is invertible for any real $a>0$.

I am not able to make any significant progress on this question . I also tried by google searching and search on this website but I am not able to find any help for any of the results.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Show that $\|(T-\lambda I)x\|\ge |{\rm Im}\lambda|\,\|x\|.$ This gives that $T-\lambda I$ is injective and its range is closed. Next show that the range is dense, hence it is equal to the whole space.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Can you please write a complete answer? I am not able to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda=a+bi\notin \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\|(T-\lambda I)x\|^2=\|(T-aI)x-ibx\|^2\\ =
\|(T-aI)x\|^2+b^2\|x\|^2-2{\rm Re}\langle (T+aI)x,ibx\rangle \\ =
\|(T-aI)x\|^2+b^2\|x\|^2-2b\,{\rm Im} \langle (T+aI)x,x\rangle \\ =\|(T+aI)x\|^2+b^2\|x\|^2\ge b^2\|x\|^2$$
Therefore
$$\|(T-\lambda I)x\|\ge |b|\,\|x\|\quad (*)$$
This implies that $\ker (T-\lambda I)=\{0\}.$ Moreover the range of $T-\lambda I$ is closed. Indeed assume  $(T-\lambda I)x_n\to y.$ By $(*)$ we get
$$\|(T-\lambda I)x_n-(T-\lambda I)x_m\|=\|(T-\lambda I)(x_n-x_m)\|\ge |b|\|x_n-x_m\|$$ The sequence $x_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition hence $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in H.$ Then $(T-\lambda I)x_n\to (T-\lambda I)x.$ Hence $y=(T-\lambda I)x,$ i.e. $y$ belongs to the range of $T-\lambda I.$

By a general formula for any bounded operator $A$ we have $A(H)^\perp =\ker A^*.$ Applying this to $A=T-\lambda I$ gives
$$(T-\lambda I)(H)^\perp =\ker (T-\overline{\lambda} I)=\{0\}$$
Therefore $(T-\lambda I)(H)=H $ (mind that we already know that the range of $T-\lambda I$ is closed).

Summarizing we have obtained that $T-\lambda I$ is a bijection on $H.$ Moreover substituting $x:=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}y$ i $(*)$ gives
$$\|y\|\ge |b|\|(T-\lambda I)^{-1}y\| $$
Hence $\|(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\|\le |b|^{-1}$ which shows that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is a bounded operator.

A similar reasoning can be performed for $(2).$ For a positive operator $A$ we have $$\langle Ax,x\rangle \le \|Ax\|,\|x\|$$
For $A:=T+a I$ we thus get
$$\|x\|\,\|(T+aI)x\|\ge \langle (T+aI)x,x\rangle \ge a\|x\|^2$$
and consequently $$\|(T+aI)x\|\ge a\|x\|\quad (**)$$ Now the conclusion follows as we have obtained an analog of $(*).$

Comment: How did you wrote $=\|(T-aI)x-ibx\|^2\\ $ equals
$\|(T-aI)x\|^2+b^2\|x\|^2-2{\rm Re}\langle (T+aI)x,ibx\rangle \\ $? Can you please elaborate on this step?

Comment: In general for any two elements  $u$ and $v$ of  the complex inner product space we have $$\|u+v\|^2=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle =\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+\langle u,v\rangle +\langle v,u\rangle$$ Next $\langle v,u\rangle =\overline{\langle u,v\rangle },$ therefore the sum is equal to the double real part.

Comment: Thank you mate!